# C# sqlite reader isnt returning anything past the first hyphen in a date time

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am inserting a DateTime attribute into a sqlite database and its getting stored successfully as 2018-04-09T00:00:00.0000000-03:00 for the appropriate time.  When I attempt to retrieve it from the database it only returns 2018.  Why won't it return the full value?

my insert is:

```
using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(Utility.CONN_STR))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("INSERT into Waybill (createdOn) VALUES(@createdOn)", conn);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@createdOn", waybillP.CreatedOn);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
        }
```

createdOn is a DateTime.
My select is:

```
using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(Utility.CONN_STR))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM Waybill where WaybillId = (select max(waybillId) from Waybill);", conn);

            SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int waybillId = Convert.ToInt16(reader["waybillId"].ToString());
                var temp = reader["createdOn"].ToString();
                DateTime createdOn = DateTime.Parse(temp);
                waybill.WaybillId = waybillId;
                waybill.CreatedOn = createdOn;
            }
```

Temp is only returning 2018 instead of 2018-04-09T00:00:00.0000000-03:00.
I have tried setting the DB column to text, real, and integer with the same results. 
I have also tried using SQLites datetime formatting like so:

```
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("INSERT into Waybill (createdOn) VALUES(datetime('now'))", conn);
```

every attempt just returns 2018 no matter what the actual entry in the DB looks like.

This causes the DateTime.Parse to crash as 2018 isn't a recognized date time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you select directly from your SQLite database, is the data present there?

Comment: Sounds like you are saving a string/text rather than a Date (because a DateTime variable wont have a dash).

Comment: if you know the index of `createdOn` column in the reader then you can try `DateTime createdOn = reader.GetDateTime(columnIndex)`

Comment: A very common mistake.  Why are you converting a DateTime to a string and then Parse back to a DateTime object?  Try : DateTime createdOn = reader["createdOn"];

Comment: The data is present when I directly select from the DB.  It is indeed a dateTime.  I even tried using SQLite own datetime method.  DateTime createdOn = reader["createdOn"];  this did not return the it properly either.

Answer (score 0):

Chetan's solution worked for me since I am only returning one result and I know the contents of the reader to be able to select the index.

```
var createdOn = reader.GetDateTime(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone reaching here after so much searching:

**The Problem:**

your datetime record in your sqlite database might look like this: `2019-11-24T08:43:52.1083280Z` and when you try to parse your date field into either a `string` or `DateTime` or even a `dynamic` field you only get until the first hyphen in this case `2019`.

I'm using the `System.Data.Sqlite` and `Dapper` packages.

since I did not have enought time to investigate this thoroughly, this code helped me:

**The Solution:**

first alter your query to return something other than that date format:

```
select strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%S', created) as created from contacts
```

then you can either parse that format in your code or implement a custom `TypeHandler` for Dapper.

Parsing the custom format:

```
    DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.ParseExact(value, "yyyyMMddTHHmmss",     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), DateTimeKind.Utc)
```

Custom Dapper TypeHandler:

```
public class DateTimeHandler : SqlMapper.TypeHandler<DateTime>
{
    public override void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, DateTime value)
    {
            parameter.Value = value.ToString("YYYYMMDDTHHmmss");
    }

    public override DateTime Parse(object value)
    {
      return DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.ParseExact((string)value,     "yyyyMMddTHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), DateTimeKind.Utc);
    }
}
```

Which you have to register it in the begining of your application for example in Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler(new DateTimeHandler());
}
```